# polyglossia and algorithmicx - Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: numbering, algorithms, polyglossia, hebrew

Trying to compile a simple document using polyglossia with Hebrew as the default language:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{David CLM}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{}
  שלום
  \begin{english}
    Procedure(A)
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \State $A = 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{english}
\end{document}
```

Results in this using XeTeX:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.15     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
```

If I set the default language to English and other language to Hebrew it works fine though.

Comment: This is due to `numerals=hebrew`. If you delete it, no error happens. I am not sure about details. You can make a bug report at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues

Comment: Also there is no need for `\TeXXeTstate=1`. And it is much safer to load `algpseudocode` package before loading `polyglossia` package.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: as a matter of fact I wanted `numerals=arabic` but that doesn't compile at all. Deleting the `numerals` also doesn't compile.

Comment: If I delete the `\section{}` it does compile without the `numerals`, but the original error is stil there.

Comment: See my answer, do you still get any error with the minimal example that I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround can be the following code to be put in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\ORI@arabic\@arabic
\expandafter\pretocmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname
  {\let\@arabic\ORI@arabic}{}{}
\renewcommand{\theALG@storecount}{\ORI@arabic\c@ALG@storecount}
\makeatother
```

The strange code is meant to inject the code in the "real" macro that does the work intended for `\algoritmic`.

Comment: Should this be put in a specific location in the preamble (before/after polygossia/algorithmic etc)? I tried several positions but all resulted in the same error.

Comment: After loading algorithmic. Just put the loading of **etoolbox** with the other packages and rest of the code before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Not much has changed. Here's the modified file with the output at the bottom: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/511861/

Comment: `bidi` package automatically loads `biditools` package (the programming infrastructure of `bidi` package) that provides some tools similar to what `etoolbox` provides. Hence there is no need to load `etoolbox`, instead change `\pretocmd` to `\bidi@pretocmd`.

Comment: @daniel.jackson I get no error.

Answer (score 1):

Since, in the comment you said that you want arabic numerals, then changing your minimal example to the following works without problems with arabic numerals:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{David CLM}

\begin{document}
\section{}
  שלום
  \begin{english}
    Procedure(A)
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \State $A = 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\@sect ...stepcounter {#1}\protected@edef \@svsec 
                                                  {\@seccntformat {#1}\relax...
l.10 \section{}`

Comment: I do not get that error. Maybe your TeX distribution is not updated.